# Block read operation of ConcurrentHashMap in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, collections

I have a ConcurrentHashMap. When thread t1 will do a write operation on it then I want thread t2 cannot do any read operation on it. The read operation should then be blocked. How will I achieve this? I cannot use HashMap and synchronize it.

Comment: Then can you synchronize on the ConcurrentHashMap itself?

Comment: There is no real point in using a ConcurrentHashMap then. A simple HashMap is sufficient. Synchronize the accesses using a ReadWriteLock. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

Comment: Why use a `ConcurremtHashMap` if you don't want it concurrent?

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap provides its own synchronization, so you do not have to synchronize accesses to it explicitly.

Comment: That's only true if you don't need any atomic composite operation, like updating two entries atomically, or iterating on the map atomically, for example.